# Laravel 5.7 - Queues Jobs are too slow

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, supervisord

I use Laravel 5.7 and 3 queues jobs, the time between jobs is too long/slow.

I foreach items of RSS feeds in the first job, and I dispatch this item in second job, etc... I don't enter in details but there are some ridiculous little calculations that must not take time.

The problem is that every dispatch to a job takes a lot of time. Horizon and Telescope do not allow me to debug.

The machine I use has 32 GB of RAM, and there are several processes (15 each) that turn the tails.

```
[program:mywebsite_feeder]
command=/RunCloud/Packages/php72rc/bin/php artisan queue:work redis --queue=feeder --tries=3 --sleep=0
directory=/home/runcloud/webapps/mywebsite
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=runcloud
numprocs=15
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
```

I have this error in laravel.log:

> production.ERROR: App\Jobs\FeederJob has been attempted too many times
>   or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

Comment: Are you using "sync" queue driver? For debugging failing jobs it's good to try / catch with logging exception details to the log.

Comment: I don't want use sync, but use Redis.

Comment: If dispatch takes long time and the job supposed to take long time it might suggest that the job is run synchronously not dispatched to the queue. Check dd(env('QUEUE_DRIVER')) somewhere in your code.

Comment: It's give me : redis, not sync.

Comment: Are you calling ::dispatch or ::dispatchNow ? It would be hard to find out what is wrong without the snippet of the code. I use redis for my queues and dispatching to the queue is instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and did a lot of searches but nothing help, even there is some issues about this bug in [horizon Github](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/128) but without a useful solution. the problem is about horizon and Redis bug for heavy tasks.

finally, I switch from Redis and horizon to SQL database (whatever you use in your project for me mssql) as queue connection and it fixed the problem

notice: use `--timeout=0` in your artisan command

Comment: Why --timeout=0 ?

Comment: according to laravel docs "The --timeout option specifies how long the Laravel queue master process will wait before killing off a child queue worker that is processing a job"
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts
this flag prevents the worker from killing long run job

Answer (score 1):

by default laravel queues sleep 3 seconds when there are no jobs available.
u should use `--sleep=0` option